# I'm trying to enable Firebase OAuth to Oracle Cloud Instance

Tags: flutter, oauth, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have an Flutter app that uses OAuth to allow user to login with google account, but it get the error:

[firebase_auth/unauthorized-domain] This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console.

I already added my ip in Authorized domain on Firebase console, but it doesn´t work. I'm thinking that it not accept the IP address. Where can I find a domain address in OCI always free tier?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is the domain address for the OCI (Oracle Cloud Instance).
It follows the format of **.compute..oraclecloud.com** where:
hostname: the instance name (see the instance detail)
compute: constant
region: region where the instance is located (see the instance detail)
oraclecloud.com: constant

I just added it in the Firebase > Authentication > Authorized Domains > Add domain